# MySql if condition in replace

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm need to update thousands of records in my database and can't figure out how to do few things... I've searched around but I'm not able to find something that works like I need to. And I don't have a lot of practise with MySql & phpmyadmin

here are the things I need to do:

1. if I want to update everything except records that ends in .gif

example

```
from
31.example.com/blabla/ciao.jpg
31.example.com/lablar/hello.png
31.example.com/albalb/hallo.gif

to
40.example.com/blabla/ciao.jpg
40.example.com/lablar/hello.png
31.example.com/albalb/hallo.gif -- stays the same
```

2. if I want to replace **http://** with **https://** only on certain url/domain like

   replace all http:// to http:// if it's domain "example":

   ```
   40.example.com/blabla/ciao.jpg

   31.example.com/lablar/hello.png

   27.example.com/lablar/hello.png

   18.example.com/lablar/hello.png
   ```

   Don't change if domains isn't example.com:

   ```
   www.teestdomain.com/lablar/hello.png

   teestdomain.com/lablar/hello.png
   ```

for the second one I've tried this, but obviously this change all http to https on all link present

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'http://', 'https://')
```

and if url is has subdomains like `http://40.example.yourdomains.com` & `http://50.example.yourdomains.com`

it doesn't work properly

Comment: Provide some SQL structure and sample data, it will make it easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The first seems to be something like:

```
update t
    set col = concat('40.example.com/', substr(col, 16))
    where col like '31.example.com/%' and col not like '%.gif';
```

The second is unclear.  You say you want to replace something that is not even in the string, so it doesn't make sense.

I think the answer to your question is:  use the `where` clause for filtering the rows to update.

Comment: I've edited my question for the second one. I meant replace http to https only if it's a given domain.. and don't change if it's another one

Comment: I've a question about the code you provided... what does the **16** at the end of  the second line stands for?